# Remove characters from request.querystring

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, request.querystring

I have some code which gets the DrawingId from an url like the one below:

/Queue/Queue.aspx?Mode=Autosearch&DrawingID=188320"

My issue is after running another part of the program, that url becomes this:

/Queue/Queue.aspx?Mode=Autosearch&DrawingID=188320?DrawingRequestId=376333&doQuerySearch=true&start=&end=&Ind=&Model=&status=Open&manager=&source=&assignee=&title=&features=&parts=&pas=&customer=&number=&project=&startIndex=1&endIndex=10&pageSize=10&total=193&date=Extended&qsEnd=

Is there a good way remove everything after 188320?  Also is there a good way to extract the DrawingRequestId of 376333?

Here is the code for DrawingID:

```
public string DrawingId
{
  get
  {
   if (Request.QueryString["DrawingID"] != "" && Request.QueryString["DrawingID"] != null)
   {
     return Request.QueryString["DrawingID"];
   }
  return null;
  }
}
```

This part won't run because the DrawingId becomes incorrect:

```
List<string> featureCodes = drawingBusiness.GetFeatureCodesByDrawingId(long.Parse(DrawingId));
```

This code doesn't work because instead of DrawingId just being 188320,

it becomes 188320?DrawingRequestId=376333

Here is the javascript where I assume the problem is starting:

```
function CloseAndRefresh() {
        var parentUrl = window.top.location.href;
        if (parentUrl.indexOf("Queue/Queue.aspx") != -1) {

            if (window.location.search === "") {
                window.location.href = window.top.location
            }
            else {
                window.top.location.href = window.top.location + window.location.search;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (window.location.search === "") {
                window.location.href = window.top.location
            }
            else {
                window.top.location.href = window.top.location + window.location.search;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: RegEx. This will solve both your problems. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @sparkysword and now you've got three problems ;-)

Comment: Hah! True, @Ted. I mostly was referring to extracting from the string and removing after the certain character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the code appended to your url you can do something like:

```
var longURL = "/Queue/Queue.aspx?Mode=Autosearch&DrawingID=188320?DrawingRequestId=376333&doQuerySearch=true&start=&end=&Ind=&Model=&status=Open&manager=&source=&assignee=&title=&features=&parts=&pas=&customer=&number=&project=&startIndex=1&endIndex=10&pageSize=10&total=193&date=Extended&qsEnd=";

var shortURL = longURL.split('?').slice(0, -1).join('?');

console.log(shortURL) // "/Queue/Queue.aspx?Mode=Autosearch&DrawingID=188320"
```

To extract the `DrawingRequestId` you can do something like:

```
var longURL = "/Queue/Queue.aspx?Mode=Autosearch&DrawingID=188320?DrawingRequestId=376333&doQuerySearch=true&start=&end=&Ind=&Model=&status=Open&manager=&source=&assignee=&title=&features=&parts=&pas=&customer=&number=&project=&startIndex=1&endIndex=10&pageSize=10&total=193&date=Extended&qsEnd=";

var drawingRequestId = parseInt(longURL.substr(longURL.indexOf('DrawingRequestId=')+17, 6));

console.log(drawingRequestId) // 376333
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this example.  So that url: /Queue/Queue.aspx?Mode=Autosearch&DrawingID=188320 is my window.top.location.   I'm still not fully understanding how this works.  If I wanted to just grab /Queue/Queue.aspx  how would I go about doing that? Do you know of any way that I can set window.top.location to just point to queue.aspx?

Comment: I have a function that requires that DrawingID and I think my problems would really be solved if there was a way to clear everything after "Queue.aspx" after that function ran.

Comment: Using the same `longURL` in my answer you can do: 

`window.top.location.href = longURL.split('?')[0];`

but remember that if you do this the page will reload.

Comment: I ended up setting the setting my window.top.location to point to the file I'm working with so the query string was refreshed, which solved my issue.  Your answer does answer the question though.  Thanks for the help.